# Migrating SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to migrate my svn repository to git.

I am using [Atlassian's migration instructions](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/svn-to-git-prepping-your-team-migration)

1. First I got my authors and mapped them

   java -jar ./svn-migration-scripts.jar authors $SVN_ROOT/$SVN_PROJECT  > authors.txt
2. Then I did an svn clone

   git svn clone --stdlayout --prefix='' --authors-file=authors.mapped.txt $SVN_ROOT/$SVN_PROJECT working.git
3. Then clean-git

   java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar ../svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git --force

It fixes the branches

```
$git branch
gary1
* master
```

But not the tags

Here is my remote branches:

```
$git branch -r
gary1
origin/gary1
origin/master
tags/0.1.0+13
tags/0.1.0+24
tags/0.1.0+5
trunk
trunk@64018
trunk@64019
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Atlassian tool has changed your tags to branches. The easy fix would be to check out the tag branch

```
git checkout tags/0.1.0+13
```

Then create the needed tag on the head of that branch

```
git tag -a v0.1.0.13
```

Then merge into the appropriate branch https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

```
git checkout master
git merge tags/0.1.0+13
```